# how to access data from Eloquent query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

My Eloquent query is:

`$postcode = address::where('client_id', $bill->client_id)->where('label', $bill->location)->select('postcode')->get();`

`echo $postcode` returns`[{"postcode":"LS18 2DY"}]`

How to I return just the postcode string?

`$postcode->postcode` or `$postcode['postcode']` fail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[{"postcode":"LS18 2DY"}]` is array of object.

Since you used `->get()` you're returning more than one item that will be wrapped into array.

Restrict it to one item `->first()`

```
$postcode = address::where('client_id', $bill->client_id)->where('label', $bill->location)->select('postcode')->first();
```

**A second way**, would be

```
$postcode[0]->postcode
```

I would **recommend to use** `first()` instead of adding index.

> Check Laravel documentation for  [**retrieving a single row**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries)

Answer (score 0):

get() returns an array, you should use the get(1) or first() to get one element, or foreach to triverse the array.

```
$postcode = address::where('client_id', $bill->client_id)->where('label', $bill->location)->select('postcode')->get(1);
$postcode->postcode;
```

Comment: same result: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$postcode

Answer (score 0):

convert the collection object to an array using toArray() then access each  single data using foreach

```
$data = some collection;

foreach($data->toArray() as $single_data)
{
    echo $single_data['key for each data'];
}
```